# Hackerrank: Hash tables- Ransom note

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hashtable

trying to resolve this problem on hacker rank with Javascript:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note

Would love some help as I'm not passing all the test cases, my code is:

```
function main() {
    var m_temp = readLine().split(' ');
    var m = parseInt(m_temp[0]);
    var n = parseInt(m_temp[1]);
    magazine = readLine().split(' ');
    ransom = readLine().split(' ');
    var hashTable = {};
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ransom.length; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = ransom[i];
    }
    for (keys in hashTable) {
        if (magazine.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
            counter +=1;
        } else { 
            counter -=1;
        }
    }
    console.log(counter >= n ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

Much appreciated!!

Comment: It would be useful to know _how_ the test fails. Unless you want random fixes that may or may not be on point.

Comment: If the question is this code correct, the answer is no.

Comment: well one of the test cases has the following input:
17 15
avtq ekpvq z rdvzf m zu bof pfkzl ekpvq pfkzl bof zu ekpvq ekpvq ekpvq ekpvq z 
mz z avtq zu bof pfkzl pfkzl pfkzl rdvzf rdvzf avtq ekpvq rdvzf avtq

And the expected output is "No" which i've tested and I get No as well but it says its wrong.

Comment: @Keith If you have no valuable input to add why comment?

Comment: @LeChiffre  I'm clarifying what he's asking..

Comment: @Keith ah ok my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version I've done, it's also checking to make sure you don't use the word more than once, It's not in the spec, but too me doesn't make sense been able to use a word more than once, as in cutting out the word out of the paper.

Also a small sanity check on the parameters to make sure the count's are correct.

```js
var lines = [
  "6 4",
  "give me one grand today night",
  "give one grand today"
];

function readLine() {
  return lines.shift();
}


function main() {
    var m_temp = readLine().split(' ');
    var m = parseInt(m_temp[0]);
    var n = parseInt(m_temp[1]);
    var i;
    magazine = readLine().split(' ');
    ransom = readLine().split(' ');
    //sanity check..
    if (magazine.length !== m) 
      throw new Error('Magazine count wrong');
    if (ransom.length !== n) 
      throw new Error('Ransom count wrong');
    //build a hash of all the words in magazine
    var hashTable = {};
    for(i = 0; i < magazine.length; i++){
        var word = magazine[i];
        if (!hashTable[word]) hashTable[word] = 1;
        else hashTable[word] ++;
        //keep a count, as a word surely can only be used once.
    }
    //now loop ransom and see if all are in magazine.
    var counter = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < ransom.length; i++) {
        if (hashTable[ransom[i]]){
          counter += 1;
          hashTable[ransom[i]] --;  //word has now been used.
        }
    }
    console.log(counter >= n? "Yes":"No");
}

main();
```

Comment: `console.log(counter >= n? "Yes":"No");` I don't think there is ever a chance for `counter >= n` . Please change it to `counter == n`

Comment: @User_Targaryen What advantage do you see in doing that?..  Also if I was going to do an equal compare, I would naturally use a strict variant  "===". Although performance is not an issue here, it's worth pointing out >= is faster than ==, and if slightly faster than ===, I think this would be down to the CPU been able to short circuit >= logic, if number's where changed to floating point's, equality checks can have strange issues too.  So IMO, if a >= can be used were a ===, I would go for >=..

Comment: @User_Targaryen  Indeed, coding style is personal, I personally think >= looks better & more logical & I also think it's also less likely to do the mistake = for ==.  Apart from that, it's what the OP had, and I was trying to change as little as I could :)

Comment: Everything accepted!! According to your code, there is no way that `counter` is going to be greater than `n`, ever. So its definitely anything but logical..

Comment: @User_Targaryen  It's up to you what you choose, I can see were you coming from, but I like the safety net that >=, <= gives, for example  var a = 0.12345; while (a !== 100.12345 && a < 200) a++; console.log(a);  This gives an answer of 200.12345, and not 100.12345.  So if for example a loop counter did get promoted to a float, at best you might get wrong results, at worst an infinite loop.  And all this from checking a negative logical condition. :)  Hope that makes sense, anyway good discussion..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the following issues with your code:

- You have no logic to count the number of occurrences of a word in `magazine` which is a huge flaw.

  Consider the example where `magazine` : `give this` and `ransom` : `give give`. Your code will return `Yes` whereas the answer is `No` because there is only one `give` in `magazine`.
- I don't think that using `hasOwnProperty` is approriate here. You just want to know if a word is present in `magazine` or not. You can use `magazine.includes(hashTable[keys])` instead of `magazine.hasOwnProperty(keys)`
- Lastly, you should `hash` magazine's words and not ransom's words, and keep a count for the number of occurrences of each of the magazine words.

Try rectifying these problems and your code will surely run. You can read @Keith's code.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
try to use below code to check for correctness

static void checkMagazine(string[] magazine, string[] note)
        {
            Boolean isCorrect = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < note.Length; i++)
            {

                if (magazine.Contains(note[i]))
                {
                    if (magazine.Count(f => f == note[i]) != note.Count(f => f == note[i]))
                    {
                        isCorrect = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    isCorrect = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (isCorrect)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");
            }
        }
```